# Install4j: Always get 'could not delete {installedDir}\.install4j' during 'Uninstall previous installation'

Tags: windows, install4j

I am using install4j 6.1.3 to create installer.

There is `Uninstall previous installation` action as the first action of gthe `Installation` action set.

But when doing upgrade, I always get the error message

> could not delete {installedDir}\.install4j

during `Uninstall previous installation` action on Windows platform.

I've tried to set the `Uninstallation policy` to `If created, but not for update`, but it still not work.

Does anyone know what's the problem here?
How to avoid install4j deleting `.install4j` directory when doing upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that some process that uses a JAR file of the install4j runtime is still running, likely a launcher.

You cannot avoid deleting the runtime files during an uninstallation, you would have to make sure that no launchers are running. The "Check for running processes" action will help you to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I check the process both using 'Check for running processes' and in 'Resource Monitor', there seems no process using .install4j/i4jruntim.jar. But I still getting that error message...

Comment: Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this may be fixed.

Comment: Thank you! I'll contact support for it :)

Comment: Too bad, even use the new build - 6.1.6 from support , I still get that error message...  
Uninstalling previous version  
could not delete C:\Program Files\{myproject}\.install4j